# Fortran/C Interlanguage problems: results differ in the 14th digit

Tags: c, fortran, floating-accuracy

I have to use C and Fortran together to do some simulations. In their course I use the same memory in both programming language parts, by defining a pointer in C to access memory allocated by Fortran.
The datatype of the problematic variable is

```
real(kind=8)
```

for Fortran, and

```
double
```

for C. The results of the same calculations now differ in the respective programming languages, and I need to directly compare them and get a zero. All calculations are done only with the above accuracies. The difference is always in the 13-14th digit.

What would be a good way to resolve this? Any compiler-flags? Just cut-off after some digits?

Many thanks!

Comment: floating point computations arent exact.  changing processor, changing compiler, optimization flag, or looking at it funny may very well change result.

Comment: You'll even get differences running the same code on different processors.

Comment: 10^-13 precision is pretty accurate. Even quantum mechanics don't need as much precision. It is like a 1µm error on the diameter of earth.

Comment: Can we have an indication on what your program does ?

Comment: First, check that this is the difference in binary values, not in the string representation. Different runtimes may use different ways to do a textual representation of a certain number.

Comment: Are you on x86, by any chance?

Comment: @Alexandre C.: I definitely need more than 4 bytes of precision, so I have to use double, don't I? But switching to a lesser precision would not solve the problem. The problem is the difference IN the output precision, whichever that is.

Comment: @caf: I am using a 2.8 Ghz Intel Core 2 Duo with Mac OS 10.6.6. I hope that is what you wanted to know ;)

Comment: @mbaitoff: The problems arise in a bigger than operation, which uses the binary values, if i'm not mistaken.

Comment: @Nils_M: Doing a bunch of addition/substractions will already spoil up a few bytes. Using double precision means that your program will be more tolerant to accumulating roundoff error, not that you will get results with full double precision. For instance, when you look for the minimum of a function, the accuracy on the minimum point is usually *half the digits* of the accuracy on the function. You sometimes have to be happy with 10^3 precision, and tell yourself that using floats would have gotten you nonsensical results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Floating point is not perfectly accurate. Ever. [Even `cos(x) == cos(y)` can be false if `x == y`.](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/newbie.html)

So when doing your comparisons, take this into account, and allow the values to differ by some small epsilon value.

Comment: An alternate solution which might be useful to you is to use someone's implementation of arbitrary precision numbers, or implement your own storage and calculation regime in integer space.

Comment: I introduced a small epsilon and it works fine. Thanks! Due to the scale of the project I couldn't test out the other proposed solutions, but I think they look be worth a try, too.

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem with the inaccuracy with floating point numbers - they will be inaccurate and a certain place. You usually compare them either by rounding them to a digit that you know will be in the accurate area, or by providing an epsilon of appropiate value (small enough to not impact further calculations, and big enough to take care of the inaccuracy while comparing).

Answer (score 2):

One thing you might check is to be sure that the [FPU control word](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/compilerpro/en-us/fortran/lin/compiler_f/fpops/fortran/fpops_contw_f.htm) is the same in both cases. If it is set to 53-bit precision in one case and 64-bit in the other, it would likely produce different results.  You can use the instructions `fstcw` and `fldcw` to read and load the control word value. Nonetheless, as others have mentioned, you should not depend on the accuracy being identical even if you can make it work in one situation.

Answer (score 1):

Perfect portability is very difficult to achieve in floating point operations.   Changing the order of the machine instructions might change the rounding.   One compiler might keep values in registers, while another copy it to memory, which can change the precision.   Currently the Fortran and C languages allow a certain amount of latitude.  The IEEE module of Fortran 2008, when implemented, will allow requiring more specific and therefore more portable floating point computations.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are compiling for an x86 architecture, it's likely that one of the compilers is maintaining intermediate values in floating point registers, which are 80 bits as opposed to the 64 bits of a C `double`.

For GCC, you can supply the `-ffloat-store` option to inhibit this optimisation.  You *may* also need to change the code to explicitly store some intermediate results in `double` variables.  Some experimentation is likely in order.